# Получение независимого от устройства времени

Tags: java, android, время

Разрабатываю программу одной из функций которой является фиксация определённых событий по времени, необходимо получать текущее время и дату как-то независимо от устройства по координатам GPS например, ибо пользователь может переводить часы и мухлевать, или может просто надо проверять настройки автоматического получения времени и часового пояса из сети...
Гуру подскажите пожалуйста

Answer (score 2):

Была как-то у меня похожая задача. Сразу скажу, что панацеи нет.
Я написал свое решение и описал его в статье http://habrahabr.ru/company/etransport/blog/245477/

Answer (score 1):

1. создайте службу *фиксация времени* - который каждую секунду берет `current_timestamp` и сравнивает со своим. Если нормально берет разницу времени и добавляет в общее время. Общее время сохраняет в `ShaerdReference`
2. программа когда нужна дата берет данные из `ShaerdReference` - это будет реальная дата использования программы.

Comment: Кроме GPS остальные варианты предполагают связь с внешним миром. Пишите события аудита на сервер и в SQL запросе используйте SYSDATE(). Уж на сервере пользователь время не сдвинет.

Comment: @SergeyMitrofanov Связь с внешним миром не проблема, проблема время в конкретной точке нашей планеты. Я как вижу реализацию: передаём координаты  - получаем время с учётом часового пояса и особенностей конкретной территории, например всякие переходы на зимнее летнее в разных странах. может есть какой сервис API  в тырнете для этих целей

Comment: В любой точке нашей планеты время одинаковое. Клиент сам должен озаботиться о переводе времени в локальное https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать запрос к более-менее любому [NTP серверу](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol) и запросить текущее мировое время. В принципе Android девайс все равно получает время от NTP сервера, но обращение к нему недокументировано и [сокрыто в непубличном API](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.robolectric/android-all/4.4_r1-robolectric-1/android/net/SntpClient.java).

Далее применить [Google Maps Time Zone API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/timezone/intro) - то есть задав координаты точки получить его TZ (временную зону). Тогда зная мировое время и TZ точки можно получить локальное время в указанной точке координат.

Answer (score 0):

[Coordinates to Time API](http://worldtime.io/api/geo)
Know the coordinates? You know the local time.

Thousands of people rely on our services every day for their time related needs and now the WorldTime.io Local Time API Service™

Вот что мне нужно только бесплатно ))))

Comment: ну и сам себе отвечу
[stackoverflow статья] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16086962/how-to-get-a-time-zone-from-a-location-using-latitude-and-longitude-coordinates) а там TimeZoneDB

Comment: Эммм... Может я чего-то не понимаю, но может не заморачиваться с координатами и просто запросить серверное время? К чему вся эта манипуляция: координаты - сервер - время ?